# Is it possible to remove a bottom border on input textfield, under the new char?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just received this visual design:

[image]

CLG is a `label` tag, while the line is an `input type=tel`
Just ignore the purple overlay...

The designer asks me to remove the border as the user types a new number.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can create a method on `focus` and check if the input has a `value`, if it does, remove the border bottom

Comment: @RazvanBalosin The trouble is the OP wants to partially remove the border, and only have it appear where there are no characters

Comment: Well, if i remove the border-bottom, it will be all removed. I need a partial removal...

Comment: Exactly, James... That's the thing.

Comment: I think the best you're going to get is by using some sort of masked input that uses `_` as placeholders.  See the demo [here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for instance.  Will leave as a comment rather an answer as it doesn't really answer the "partial border" aspect of your Q.

Comment: Thank you James. I'll give a try to that approach and let you know if it worked. By far it seems the most interesting approach to this problem

Comment: X-Y Alert! What your design shows is a MaskedEdit box (eg, [here](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) but there are a million to choose from!)

Comment: Should it work on both mobile and desktop displays? Depending on your answer, I have a solution

Comment: both mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible, however it includes

- JavaScript (for checking the current input size)
- Flexbox (for auto-shrinking the border)

The idea is basically to mimick the border with a `:after` pseudo-element and shrink it to the remaining width of the `<label>`.

```js
// https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('input', function() {
    element.size = element.value.length;
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  font-weight: bold;
}
label:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
input {
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>CLG <input type="tel" size="1"></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Seems to work better with fixed width font and no outline.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `input` element, I used a div element with `contenteditable` property.

```
.wrapper {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
.text {
    position: relative;
    min-width:10px;
}
.text:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.text:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3tfax9u/3/)

Comment: I know this has many issues. it is just a workaround to show you what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse, (almost) everything is possible.

```js
$(function() {
  $('span').html($('input').val()); /* on page load */
  $('input').on('keyup', function() { /* on keyup */
    $(this).next('span').html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
label {
  position: relative;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 31px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  CLG
  <input type="text" value="0123" />
  <span></span>
</label>
```

The label functions as a wrapper element (placed relative). So a span can be placed absolute and it's position relative to the label. The span has height, the same as the border bottom and a white color.

When the page is loaded, or the inputs value gets changed. The HTML inside the span gets changed as well. Making it overlay the border.

Note that the font-size inside the input and span need to be exactly the same.

Also, the starting point of the span is relative to the label, not to the input (because the input has no ending tag, you can't apply it to that). So when changing the CLG text or its font, you'll need to change the starting point of the span as well.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```js
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
  this.each(function(index, elem) {
    if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
      elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
    }
  });
  return this;
};

$("document").ready(function() {
  var maxlen = $("#txtVal").attr("maxlength");
  var underscore = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < maxlen - 1; i++) {
    underscore = underscore + '_';
  }
  $("#txtVal").val(underscore);

  $("#txtVal").click(function() {
    var inputText = $("#txtVal").val();
    var inputValue = inputText.replace(/_/g, "");
    $("#txtVal").focus().setCursorPosition(inputValue.length);
  });

  $("#txtVal").keyup(function() {
    var inputText = $("#txtVal").val();
    var inputValue = inputText.replace(/_/g, "");
    var underscores = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < (maxlen - inputValue.length) - 1; i++) {
      underscores = underscores + '_';
    }

    $("#txtVal").val(inputValue + underscores);
    $("#txtVal").focus().setCursorPosition(inputValue.length);

  });

  $("#txtVal").blur(function() {
    var len = $("#txtVal").val().length;
    $("#txtVal").attr("maxlength", parseInt(len) + 1);
  });

});
```

```css
#txtVal {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
CGL :
<input type="tel" id="txtVal" maxlength="30" />
```

Thanks